# Spring REST Docs throwing MustacheException

Tags: java, spring-boot, mustache, spring-restdocs

I am getting a weird exception with a trouble on non-existing field either on my response or request. I have configuration setup to generate snippets for response/requests on my endpoints with documentation on the fields of those beans. Except I am getting the following exception from `org.springframework.restdocs.mustache` package;

```
MustacheException$Context: No method or field with name 'required' on line 6
```

I have no `'required'` field declared anywhere on my descriptor snippets, or within my request/response beans, and what is the deal with `line 6`? What a mysterious exception! What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble stemmed from a custom `request-parameters` template, in `src/test/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates/` resource folder. Due to the addition of a custom field within the template of request descriptor, the lack of this field was causing the issue. `List 6` was where the `'request'` field was being used within this file, thus the error.

Removing the custom template to let REST Docs use its default template resolved the issue.